# Google Script Function onEdit()

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm learning how to use the google apps scripts with google sheets, and im using the script below to test. What it basic do is call the function `onEdit()` and store de value before altered in `vCellOld` and the new value in `vCellNew` and then, shows a messagebox whit these two values. After tha I'm trying to store the `vCellOld` in the next cell on the same line but is not working. Can anyone help me with this!?

```
function onEdit(e)
{
  //Store the old value
  var vCellOld = e.oldValue;
  //Store the new value
  var vCellNew = e.value;
  //Shows a message box with the old and new values
  Browser.msgBox("valor antigo: " + vCellOld + " valor novo: " + vCellNew);

  //HERE SHOULD STORE THE OLD VALUE ON THE NEXT RESPECTIVE CELL
  var nCell = e.range.Offset(0,1);
  ncell.setValue(vCellOld);

}
```

Comment: I'm not aware of `Range#Offset`. Did you mean `Range#offset`?

Comment: Yes, but it did't work too!

Comment: Another thing that I notice, is the `nCell ` is with c lowecase. I fixed and didn't work too! `var nCell = e.range.offset(0,1); nCell.setValue(vCellOld);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you fix the errors you say you fixed, it works for me.

```
function onEdit(e)
{
  //Store the old value
  var vCellOld = e.oldValue;
  //Store the new value
  var vCellNew = e.value;
  //Shows a message box with the old and new values
  Browser.msgBox("Old Value: " + vCellOld + " New Value: " + vCellNew);

  //HERE SHOULD STORE THE OLD VALUE ON THE NEXT RESPECTIVE CELL
  var nCell = e.range.offset(0,1);
  nCell.setValue(vCellOld);

}
```

Notification

[image: Notification]

Replacement

[image: Replacement]

Comment: I don't know why, but just copying your code that worked for me! Anyway, thanks a lot!